# Google Maps Marker Cluster Sum Value

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I currently have an app that creates an array of markers. But it is not useful, because I would like to see a group of markers and a custom property summed based on the distance between markers (depending on the zoom level).

I've said that maybe with MarkerClusterPlus I could accomplish something like this: [image: Example of property 'Earning' summed and grouped in a cluster]
This even shows a custom icon, I don't need that, I only need the number over the cluster.

But I don't know where to start. Could someone place an example or a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define a custom property on the Marker object, so you can override the Calculator function in markercluster.js

```
MarkerClusterer.CALCULATOR = function (markers, numStyles) {
  var index = 0;
  var title = "";
  var count = markers.length.toString();

  var valueToSum=0;

  for(var m=0;m<markers.length;m++){
     //This is the custom property called MyValue
     valueToSum+=Number(markers[m].MyValue);
  }

  var dv = val;

  while (dv !== 0) {
     dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);  //you could define your own rules
     index++;
  }

  index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
  return {
     text: valueToSum,
     index: index,
     title: title
  };
};
```

Comment: Hi there, in your answer I understand that you managed to get the "sum text" value. Did you achieved the "custom icon" based on the subproperty of this sum ? (pie chart with different ratio of colors based on what is inside)